# How to Intergrate Alfresco with an Web application?

Tags: authentication, alfresco

I want to intergrate alfresco with web application. i.e i have created a login page for my application.Now i want to use the same username and password to login to alfresco so that i dont have to login again using alfresco login page. Can anyone help me out in this?

Thanks and regards,
than1234

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to **login** in http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference

Answer (score 0):

Also look for SSO (Single-Sign On)... it would not only avoid your users to re-login to Alfresco, but to other applications. There is information in the manual, the wiki.alfresco.com site, and just by Googling. There are multiple ways to doing it, and choosing will depend on the protocols that you are using. Happy SSO'ing!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Login

When you make a HTTP GET request to "/alfresco/service/api/login?u={username}&pw={password?}" you get alf_ticket back which you then use in following request instead of loging in each time.

You just append "&alf_ticket=YOUR_TICKET" in your requests... :)

Comment: I would probably suggest you post the username and password as JSON, so the credentials don't end up in your log files!